# Area 51 Account not showing in Account List on Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, profile-page, linked-accounts

I have 12 accounts across the SE network.  As of sometime the afternoon, my Area 51 account disappeared from my Account Listing on my account profile page for every site upon which I have an account, except Area 51.  My SE Network Profile also lists it.

Is this a new change or a bug?

Comment: They're probably doing something with the Area 51 cache data. I'm sure it will return shortly. Just to point out, it appears to be doing this for all users who have an Area 51 account.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We made several changes to how the Accounts tab works on the backend over the last few days; it needed one more tweak for the Area 51 piece...which is now deployed.